# get a error when i run example code in javafx using Oracle documentation

Tags: linux, javafx, java

firstly i've downloaded openjdk and run javafx project. but, javaFX is not included in it.

so that,
Now I've downloaded OracleJDK 8 via `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` Its resolve that problem.

However, I'm getting new problem. when i try to run Hello World example from Oracle Documentation, I get this error in console.

```
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
```

and, windows space is white.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JavaFX are you using? Please, note FX2.x is not supported on RedHat/OEL. But FX8 is, you may want to try dev releases of FX8: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Regarding FX8:

Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4 message is not an error but notification message. It will be removed in jdk8 release: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-29273

GThread-ERROR from samples is another story. It's an issue which may be not yet fixed. See https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-32436 and https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28580#comment-358413